# Google cloud run domain mapping and custom domains-google cloud load balancing can it have two same domain name but in only one cloud run service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, subdomain, load-balancing, google-cloud-run

I have created a subdomain in google cloud run using cloud run domain mappings.

My question is can i create same subdomain name using custom domains-google cloud load balancing

eg :- dev.test.us current running in cloud run domain mapping while same domain can i create in custom domains-google cloud load balancing

Godaddy is main domain and subdomain register

https://dev.test.us (cloud run domain mapping) (I used CNAME records)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsd5d.png)
https://dev.test.us (custom domains-google cloud load balancing) (I used A records)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCkw7.png)

I need clarified will same domain name can i use on both but its connect to only service. U can say one service is running in google cloud run can have 2 same domain but with different one is cloud run domain mapping and another is custom domains-google cloud load balancing

if its ok then let me know otherwise let me know if its no ok

Here is screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH1IK.png)

Comment: A domain name can point to more than one resource using A and AAAA DNS resource records but that is not what you want to do in your example. So the answer is no. Move the DNS record to point to the load balancer and configure Cloud Run as a backend (NEG) to the load balancer.

Comment: how can i configure cloud run as a backend(NEG)

Comment: Google documents that. Too many steps to answer via a comment.